# Converting hex values to string

Tags: sql, sql-server, db2

I have a linked server setup retrieving data from an openquery it's a db2 connection to an ibmi file, but the file has a CCSID of 65535, which when I return the data in SSMS, appears to be in hexidecimal and therefore returns the following;

0xC7

The value should be a 'G'.

Is there a way I can convert these values when bringing them into SQL via openquery?

Comment: what driver are you using to connect to the iSeries box?  Ideally the CCSID should be corrected on the iSeries.  One option would be a view.  E.g. see the discussion here https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=36581621-ddec-48f4-be92-f0feb59438c8

Answer (score 0):

use convert function

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(64), 0xC7, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT convert(varchar, 0x'Hex value')`

OR YOU MAY USE

```
SELECT Convert(varchar, 0x+<columnName>)
```

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/6bfe99c8-c662-44bf-ae10-74b4a00d4da7/hex-to-string?forum=transactsql